# AMD 5700XT not being used in Cycles Blender 3.0.0

Tags: rendering, gpu

I've installed the recommended AMD Pro drivers. The GPU displays under the HIP system settings and is selected.

When rendering out a scene, the GPU usage doesn't spike at all and the render takes an age. If I tick the CPU then the CPU maxes out. I've also tried a much smaller scene with the same result.

Anyone any insights? I'd purchase an Nvidia card but they just can't be had!

Comment: You should check `User Preferences` > `System` > `Cycles Render Devices` to see if your GPU is not under one of the tabs then your GPU is probably not supported. Blender 3.0 dropped support for OpenCL so if that's what your GPU uses, it won't be supported.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned, the GPU is displayed and selected as the render device. I know there is an official AMD compatibility list for the 6000 series of GPU's and the 5700xt isn't on that list. But it is showing in the list of render devices but just not being used. I was wondering if there was some other settings or something I'm missing.

Comment: There is only a few bunch of AMD GPU's that are supported by 3.0 and it's listed here https://code.blender.org/2021/11/next-level-support-for-amd-gpus/ and, indeed, your 5700XT is not there so that's probably the reason for your problem, I don't understand why it is still listed in the render devices tho.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that's what's a little confusing, that it shows up at all. This link here https://community.amd.com/t5/radeon-pro-graphics/blender-3-0-and-amd-creating-a-new-performance-path/ba-p/499333 seems to indicate that it is indeed supported.

Comment: This beats me. The mere fact that it shows in your render devices implies that there is no driver problem so I have no idea why it is not used by Blender. Either it's an OS problem or a bug with Blender, maybe you should report it?